# Is this a conflict of interest?

Tags: conflict-of-interest

I am having an internal interview next week for a higher level position within my organization.  I have been with the organization for 12 years now.  We recently brought on a new hire about 5 months ago.  I was actually a panel member for when she was interviewed and hired. So I served on the interviewing/hiring panel when she was interviewed and hired as a result.

I, myself, am now up for this higher level position as a supervisor, but have come to find out that this new hire is being included as a panel member to now interview me for a higher level position.  Is this a conflict of interest if I previously served as a panel interviewer for her own interview with us, and now she will be asked to interview me after only 5 months and for a supervisory position that includes being her supervisor? What are the thoughts on this?

I simply cannot fathom that this is ok for someone I helped evaluate as a new hire candidate is going to pass judgement on me after being with us only 5 months and still not knowing the ropes. Thoughts?

Comment: Since you're asking for thoughts, I think giving employees a say in who their manager should be seems like a great way to give them a sense of empowerment and autonomy in their work life. Just my opinion.

Comment: If it is a conflict of interest I would think that it's actually in your favor. After all you are in part why she got the job.

Answer (score 9):

I don't think you're understanding the term "conflict of interest" correctly - there would only be a conflict if the panel member (i.e. the new hire) actually had reasons to act *against* the best interests of the interview panel because you were on the hiring panel for them e.g. you had offered to them that you would assist in getting them hired if they helped you later.

The fact that you would be their supervisor in this scenario isn't a conflict - it sounds more likely the companies way of trying to ensure that the new supervisor is going to have a suitable rapport with those they are going to be supervising. In many cases this is a Good Thing(TM) (and frankly it's something I wish more companies did when forming interview panels).

People aren't robots (most of them anyway) so sure it's not out of the realms of possibility that this person may feel favorably inclined towards you if you were partly responsible for them getting the job but that's just part and parcel of normal, human, life. You shouldn't overthink this - just go to the interview and do your best as you would whether this person was there or not.

Comment: _'People aren't robots'_ .Doogle and VueDube ask me all the time to verify that i'm not a robot..

Comment: @iLuvLogix Do they offer to patch you up with some hot resin? What sort of robot turns down a free blast of searing-hot resin?

Comment: mhhhhh - searing-hot resin and a security patch for my mqtt corona subscription make my day ;)

Comment: @iLuvLogix Which of the following would you most prefer? A, a puppy; B, a pretty flower from your sweetie or; C, a large properly-formatted data file?

Comment: C - but to be precise it must be valid JSON according to draft 6 ;)

Comment: @iLuvLogix Correct. The flower would also have been acceptable.

Comment: For reasoning: Puppies are overrated and and their internal interpreter & compiler won't compute my commands. And a flower - well, is a flower but exactly just that..

Comment: I would only prefer the flower if it was broken down 3-dimensionally in stereo-lithographic data and passed jslint according to the specs above..

Answer (score 8):

**The goal of interviews is usually not neutrality.**

The exact goal of an interview will vary by company, but the goal is rarely a cold evaluation of skill. I have heard of several companies where subordinates get to help to interview the new boss because they need to work with that person and that person will need to command their respect. Subordinates need to know that their boss can train them. They need to know that their boss can lead them. They need a boss who can communicate well with them. They need to know that their boss is not going to screw them or abuse them.

There is minimal of interest because the interests of the company and the interests of the supervised employees can easily align in several areas when it comes to the hiring of supervisors. If anything, the fact that you helped her hire would be the major conflict, not the fact that you will supervise her.